# Comparison of text color in UILabel with UIColor fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to compare the text colour in a UIlabel with a UIColor but the result is always false.

The following code produces the result:

```
color equal 1, 0
```

I expect both a and b to be equal to 1. Is there another way to do this compare?

```
    bool a,b;

    UIColor *myColor1, *myColor2;

    myColor1 = [UIColor redColor];
    mainViewController.timerLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    myColor2 = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:mainViewController.timerLabel.textColor.CGColor];


    a = [[UIColor redColor] isEqual:myColor1];
    b = [[UIColor redColor] isEqual:myColor2];

    NSLog(@"color equal %i, %i",a,b);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UIColor does not define isEqual, isEqual is inherited from NSObject.  Thus isEqual is comparing the addresses of the colors and will fail.

CGColor has a comparison function `CGColorEqualToColor()`:

```
CGColor *c = myColor.CGColor;
```

Then the CGColor colors can be compared:

```
bool colorsEqual = CGColorEqualToColor(myColor1.CGColor, myColor2.CGColor);
```

Or get the individual components of the two colors and compare then individually using
`- (BOOL)getRed:(CGFloat *)red green:(CGFloat *)green blue:(CGFloat *)blue alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha`